# Vuetify, scroll two containers at the same time

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a couple of divs with `overflow: scroll`, when I click an element in `div A` the `goTo` function scrolls `div A` into the position of that element:

```js
this.$vuetify.goTo(<clicked element ref>, {
  container: <div A>
})
```

But I also want to trigger scrolling in div B to a certain arbitrary position, simply duplicating the first goto function is not working:

```js
this.$vuetify.goTo(<arbitrary element in div B>, {
  container: <div B>
})
```

Using js vanilla methods in that second Div works, but I'm looking a solution only using Vuetify.